Laravel 'paginate' have different ordered results as to simply using 'get()'
I'm trying to get data, using this query
$game->teams()->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN position IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC')->orderBy('position')->with(['user'])->get()

it has the correct results and orders,
but when I try to paginate it, of course by replacing ->get() with ->paginate(15), now the data is incorrect.
some data in top 15 when using get() isn't there anymore when using paginate, and supposedly, the results when using get() are distinct, but on paginate, some items are still present in page 2.
btw, i have this orderByRaw('CASE WHEN position IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC') query to put null positions to last.

The issue you’re encountering arises because the pagination method ->paginate() may not preserve the order of results in the same way as ->get(). When paginating, the database query is often modified, which can affect the order and consistency of results.
Here’s a solution to ensure consistent ordering when paginating:
1. Ensure Consistent Ordering: Ensure that your order by clause is properly applied in both cases. This includes ordering by an additional unique identifier (such as id) to guarantee a consistent order when paginating.

Use a Unique Identifier for Consistent Ordering: Add a secondary order by clause on a unique column (such as id) to maintain consistent order.

Here's how you can modify your query:
  $game->teams()
    ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN position IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC')
    ->orderBy('position')
    ->orderBy('id') // Ensure consistent ordering by adding a unique identifier
    ->with(['user'])
    ->paginate(15);

Explanation

orderByRaw('CASE WHEN position IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC'): This ensures that entries with a null position are placed at the end.
orderBy('position'): This orders the remaining entries by the position column.
orderBy('id'): Adding this ensures that if there are rows with the same position, they are consistently ordered by id, which is unique.

Additional Considerations

Check for Model Scopes or Global Scopes: Ensure that there are no model scopes or global scopes that might interfere with your query when using paginate().

Debugging SQL Queries: Use Laravel's toSql() method to debug and see the actual SQL query being executed. This can help you understand how the query changes between get() and paginate().
$sqlQuery = $game->teams()
->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN position IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC')
->orderBy('position')
->orderBy('id')
->with(['user'])
->toSql();


dd($sqlQuery); // Debug the SQL query
By ensuring the order by clauses are consistently applied and adding a unique identifier for additional ordering, you should be able to achieve consistent results between get() and paginate().

Did AI write that answer? fyi: Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?
